# Download older version of SonarPLSQL plugin

Tags: plsql, sonarqube

Where can I find older versions of the SOnarPLSQL plugin ?

My Sonar Server is on 6.1 version,so the latest plugin doesn't work for the current server.

In the main link https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/SonarPLSQL  only the release notes are available and not old binaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow similar link to the [download SonarPLSQL](https://sonarsource.bintray.com/CommercialDistribution/sonar-plsql-plugin/) to see more versions as `sonar-plsql-plugin-2.7.1.jar`

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. It helped me